# summing select columns along axis-1 in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to sum up values along the row of certain columns in pandas.
I have a 2d list that looks like this:

```
sample_list = [['A','B','C'], ['D','E','F'], ['G','H','I'], ['J','K','L'], ['M','N','O'], ['P','Q','R']]
```

My intention is to loop through each list eleemnt within sample_list, with each loop creating a new column in my DF with a number associated with the element number of the new list df['trial0'], df['trial1'], ......, df['trial99'], df['trial100'], and it sums up the selected columns specified within each list with sample_list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R'])

for x in range(0, len(sample_list)):
    df[f'sum_of_list{x}'] = df.sum(axis=1, columns=sample_list[x])
```

I'm sure the argument used in my df.sum() example is wrong.  How would I go about doing this?

Thank you

Comment: Kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
for x in range(0, len(sample_list)):
    df[f'sum_of_list{x}'] = df[sample_list[x]].sum(axis=1)
```